# Hive INSERT INTO vs UNION ALL performance

Tags: hive, hiveql, insert-into, union-all

Lets say I have two tables A and B with same schema and 1 Million rows each,
I can add values in table A and B into a table C using either a `UNION ALL` or two `INSERT INTO` statements.

I actually did it and found that the INSERT INTO did better, but I would like to know why? And is UNION ALL better in any specific scenario?

Comment: Try to execute it on Tez, it will run each query in parallel and will put files into subfolders.

Comment: @leftjoin tez isn't configured on my cluster, more over I am interested to know what is the internal difference between the two methods?

Comment: And how can we know internal difference on your cluster without logs and query plan. It may be misconfiguration problem. Internal difference depends on configuration much.

Comment: @leftjoin how `inner join` or `union all` works in hive is defined in its internal code, not on my cluster.
Don't comment unless you have something useful to add.

Comment: How Union all works also depends on configuration. For example this: `hive.exec.parallel` Query plan end execution logs may show  how it is being executed and what is the reason of slowdown.